# How to add a second legend for subgroups in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am making a plot using matplotlib which uses a colormap to show different colors for each subgroup within the plot. However for plotting purposes the subgroups are all one set of x/y pairs.

```
plt.scatter(rs1.x,rs1.y, marker = 'D', color=cmap ,label='data')
plt.plot(rs1.x,rs1.hub_results.predict(), marker = 'x', color = 'g',label = 'Huber Fit')
plt.plot(rs1.ol_x,rs1.ol_y, marker = 'x', color='r', ms=10, mew=2, linestyle = ' ', label='Outliers')
```

It gives the image shown below. It is giving me the colors as I mapped them so that part is working fine, but I have not been able to figure out how to add a second legend to the plot to show what the meaning of each color is. Apprecaite any guidance on this.

Thanks, 
Charlie

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is an example of how to do this. Basically, you end up making two calls to `legend`. On the first call, you save the legend that is created to a variable. The second call removes the first legend you created, so afterwards you can manually add it back with the `Axes.add_artist` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 4)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 4)

p1, = plt.plot([1,2,3])
p2, = plt.plot([3,2,1])
l1 = plt.legend([p2, p1], ["line 2", "line 1"], loc='upper left')

p3 = plt.scatter(x[0:2], y[0:2], marker = 'D', color='r')
p4 = plt.scatter(x[2:], y[2:], marker = 'D', color='g')

# This removes l1 from the axes.
plt.legend([p3, p4], ['label', 'label1'], loc='lower right', scatterpoints=1)
# Add l1 as a separate artist to the axes
plt.gca().add_artist(l1)
```

[image: Two labels]

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you! I just have one follow-up: Is it possible to place the second legend (the one using "add_artist" somewhere beyond the interior of the chart where the data is? For exmaple in the chart you show, if I could put the second legend such that its leftmost edge is just a little to the left of the vertical line at x=2.5, that would be perfect. I do have room on the page for that if there is a way to move it there.

Comment: I see that my follow-up question is in fact answered pretty clearly right there in the matplotlib documentation. Apologies for not checking there first. The answer to my followup queesion is located here: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html